# Add Param to Paypal Transaction

Tags: magento, post, paypal

When a customer makes a paypal transaction, how can I add a parameter to their purchase?  The item(s) and price come through fine, but I have an additional field on checkout that isn't being captured when purchasing through paypal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a hosted button?  If so, you can't add your own data directly.  It would have to be done in the button manager, and it's very limited there because you can't use dynamic variables as values.

With non-hosted button code, you can add a parameter called "custom" and put anything you want there up to 256 characters.  This will come back in IPN as a POST variable named "custom" as well.

If you're unsure about whether your button is hosted or not just look at the HTML they gave you to paste into your page.  If it has a hosted_button_id you know it's hosted.

Comment: No, it's part of the integrated payment methods